# Python Plotly : Set individual fixed height and width for all subplots when using facet_col

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

When setting a fixed height, e.g. `height=400`, while using `facet_col`, the height and width of each individual subplot are distributed among the overall height and width of the plotly chart area. If the number of subplots is variable, then so is the height and width of the subplots. Is there a way to set an indivdual fixed height and width for all subplots?

Currently – as a crude workaround – I am counting how many rows there are in the `pandas.DataFrame` I am passing to Plotly, then using an imprecise formula to get some semblance of fixed height. I am using `facet_col_wrap=1` to get a fixed width.

Example code (taken from: https://plotly.com/python/facet-plots/):

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks(indexed=True)

fig = px.line(
    df,
    facet_col="company",
    facet_col_wrap=1 # workaround fixed width
    height=400 + (n_company * 200)) # workaround fixed height

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

plotly.express cannot set individual graph sizes. You can control row height and column width in a subplot using a graph object. The sum of the ratios is determined by the number of rows or columns so that the ratio sums to 1. In this case, I chose to repeat 0.3 and 0.2. See the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/#customize-subplot-column-widths-and-row-heights) for more details.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = px.data.stocks(indexed=True)
fig = make_subplots(rows=4, cols=1, row_heights=[0.30,0.20,0.30,0.20])

for i,ticker in enumerate(df.columns[:4]):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='lines', x=df.index, y=df[ticker], name=ticker),row=i+1, col=1)
    
fig.update_layout(autosize=True,
                  height=600,
                 )
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could recalculate the total facet area height or width if you have the desired facet dimension and the number of rows or columns.

Depending on accuracy you can go from simple:

> dimension = facet_dimension * number_rowscols

You can take into consideration spacing:

> dimension = facet_dimension * number_rowscols / (1 - spacing *
> (number_rowscols - 1))

But all of these will return a smaller size facet, because there's also the margin. So to get the exact size you'd need to dig deep into plotly code and figure out the size calculation.